# iOS 4 Multitasking Tutorial

Tags: ios4, multitasking

I've been looking on google and I've got to page 10 of the results and I still did not find any good guide on how to implement multitasking into my application.

Anyone has a good one?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apple's own guide to multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a few notes on iOS Multitasking. It is not exactly a guide, but maybe useful for a start:

Two parts

- Part 1 http://www.christian-fries.de/blog/files/20010-06-iOSMultitaksing.html
- Part 2 http://www.christian-fries.de/blog/files/2010-07-ios.html